# How to search few values in quick filter using commas - ag grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

Is it possible to filter few values in ag grid split by commas?

For example if i search **aa,bb,cc** -  I want to get all rows that contains on of these values - aa **or** bb **or** cc.

my code now works only for one value:

```html
   onFilterTextBoxChanged(value) {
      this.gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(value);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found to do it is using: [ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/27.0.0/vue-data-grid/filter-external/) And write all the logic by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works out of the box when you replace the commas with the space character. That's how the quick filter behaves for me. ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omMhv.png))

So I would take the search string input containing commas, and internally call setQuickFilter() where commas in the search string have been replaced by spaces.